# Start OpenVPN on boot in CentOS 6

Tags: openvpn, centos6

On cloud I have ready my OpenVPN Server...

And my Client machine also configured and OpenVPN work perfect. but my problem setting up the client on boot.

By running below command I'm able to connect to Server without any problem

```
openvpn --config myconfig.conf --deamon myvpn
```

The same line I have added to `/etc/rc.local` but on boot I do not get connected.

really not able to troubleshoot the reason.

Comment: There are other issues, as Nils has noted (+1 from me, Nils!), but you may also have misspelled `--daemon`.

Comment: @MadHatter true that  was typo

Comment: Consider that a demonstration of why you should cut-and-paste into your SF questions, instead of retyping!

Comment: @MadHatter actually I didn't cut and paste from anywhere. this is my real problem.

Comment: You misunderstand.  I'm not suggesting you cut-and-pasted when you should not have.  I'm suggesting you *did not* cut-and-paste when you *should have*.  Specifically, when quoting commands and output therefrom in your questions, you should cut-and-paste directly from a terminal session instead of retyping.  Retyping introduces spurious typos that can conceal real problems and introduce red herrings.  Make sense?

Comment: @MadHatter sorry I really didn't understand... that really sounds good will follow in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding to Nils answer

Save myconfig.conf to `/etc/openvpn/server.conf`

Set on startup with `chkconfig --level 35 openvpn on`

Finally just restart openvpn by `service openvpn restart`

Watch log by `tail -f /var/log/messages`

Answer (score 4):

rc.local is bad style.

Normally you would add a service with

`chkconfig` to the wanted runlevels (3 and 5 in your case).

Try `chkconfig --level 35 openvpn on`

This will work if there is a proper init script in place.

Comment: Added to Nils answer...

In case of CentOS 6, the `*.ovpn` file to be placed user `/etc/openvpn/*.conf`

so centos can automatically start the openvpn client.